# How to set any font size (e.g. 32pt) with \setbeamerfont?

Tags: latex, beamer

I want to set font size for frametitle with \setbeamerfont. How to set any font size (e.g. 32pt) with \setbeamerfont?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

After reading the manual, I found the answer! It's simple:

```
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{family=\rmfamily,series=\bfseries,size={\fontsize{32}{36}}}
```

where 32 is 32pt, the font size and 36 is the skip line size in pt.

Answer (score 4):

According to the manual (version 3.09), you can also use:

```
size*={<font size>}{<baseline skip>}
```