# Adding version info to title slide

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to add some info in my title slide of my Rmarkdown-produced Beamer presentation to assure readers of the creation date of the file they're reading.

This should basically be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449319/yaml-current-date-in-rmarkdown) answer posted by Yihui, but there's a catch -- the presentation was given on a fixed date, which I'd like to keep, *below which* I would print the creation date, *a la*:

> March 1, 2016
>
> This version: March 4, 2016

I can't get the `date` field in the YAML header to play along with this multi-line approach. Pages like [this](http://assemble.io/docs/YAML-front-matter.html) suggest we can simply follow `date:` by some `-`-demarcated lists, like:

```
output:
  beamer_presentation 
date:
- March 1, 2016
- "This Version: `r Sys.time()`"
```

When compiled, only the first line is printed on the title slide. (I've also tried other similar approaches with [different white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29532605/3576984), [using pipes to denote subtitles](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html), etc.)

The closest I've gotten is to get both things on the same line with:

```
date: "March 1, 2016\nThis Version: `r Sys.time()`"
```

But the compiled version apparently ignores the newline.

Any suggestions?

---

Edit:

I've gotten a new line to appear finally by doubling the newline character `"\n"`, but am still interested in a way to make the font on "This version:..." smaller. Why didn't the subtitling through pipes approach work?

Comment: Did you try a `<br>` instead of the `\n` ?

Comment: @cory didn't work, seems to have been ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you have solved the newline problem via `\n\n` (that tells LaTeX to start a new paragraph), and the remaining question is about the font size. If you only need the LaTeX/beamer output, I think you can use LaTeX commands like `\\small{This version...}`.

Comment: Indeed you can! Is there any robust way to handle this in case I wanted to switch output style to, say HTML, at some point? Just wondering.

Comment: That will be slightly more difficult. You have to check the value of `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")`, and write out LaTeX or HTML code accordingly. You can write a function for that, and use it in the inline R expression.