# R Markdown ioslides institution name

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, r-markdown, ioslides

Is there a way to specify an institution name in ioslides? I know I can specify the title and author in the metadata,

```
---
title: "My presentation"
author: Will Landau
date: \today
---
```

but I'm having trouble finding how to add an institution or company name. Is there a metadata slot like `institution: Iowa State University`?

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532214/add-author-affiliation-in-r-markdown-beamer-presentation ?

Comment: That works. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @landau may I ask which answer works for you? Thanks!